# Runtime error when use dataset.map() with tf.numpy_function and num_parallel_calls in Colab GPU. But it runs in CPU or GPU without num_parrallel_call

Tags: dictionary, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I made a TF dataset by combine (img_path, a list of 5 caption strings).

I use map() function to transform:

- img_path to feature (read from .npy file)
- list of caption to vector by TextVectorization

When use map() with numpy_funtion, the shape of data is lost. So I use the second map() to get the shape that I want.

```
vectorization = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=SEQ_LENGTH,
    standardize=custom_standardization,
)
vectorization.adapt(text_data)

def process_input(img_path, captions):

    feat = np.load(FEATURE_DIR + '/' + img_path.decode('utf-8')[-31:-4] + '.npy')
    vect = vectorization(captions)
    return feat, vect

def _set_shapes(item1, item2):
    item1.set_shape([101, 1536])
    item2.set_shape([None, SEQ_LENGTH])
    return item1, item2

def make_dataset(images, captions):

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, captions)) # element: (img_name, [5 caps])
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 8)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda item1, item2: tf.numpy_function(func = process_input, inp = [item1, item2], Tout = [tf.float32, tf.int64]),\
                            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.map(_set_shapes, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

# Pass the list of images and the list of corresponding captions
train_dataset = make_dataset(list(train_data.keys()), list(train_data.values()))
valid_dataset = make_dataset(list(valid_data.keys()), list(valid_data.values()))
```

I build an image captioning model and feed the data for training. It runs OK in Colab CPU mode.

But when I use Colab GPU, It runs for some batchs and make runtime error. I have catch the exception and print out the data, but the data seems normal. The error is:

```
Epoch 1/10
  20/9000 [..............................] - ETA: 21:39 - loss: 46.4597 - acc: 1.5528e-04
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-f5db60e64541> in <cell line: 42>()
     40 # Fit the model
     41 
---> 42 caption_model.fit(
     43     train_dataset,
     44     epochs=EPOCHS,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   # pylint: disable=protected-access
     51   try:
---> 52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization).

{{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [2], and [2] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: text_vectorization_4/strided_slice/

Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5,), dtype=string)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 267, in __call__
    # TODO(akshayka): Key the tape cache in a thread-safe way.

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):

  File "<ipython-input-60-068fb0a18e1d>", line 12, in process_input
    vect = vectorization(captions)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7262, in raise_from_not_ok_status

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization).

{{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [2], and [2] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: text_vectorization_4/strided_slice/

Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5,), dtype=string)


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[sparse_categorical_crossentropy_4/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert/data_1/_284]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization).

{{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [2], and [2] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: text_vectorization_4/strided_slice/

Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5,), dtype=string)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 267, in __call__
    # TODO(akshayka): Key the tape cache in a thread-safe way.

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):

  File "<ipython-input-60-068fb0a18e1d>", line 12, in process_input
    vect = vectorization(captions)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7262, in raise_from_not_ok_status

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization).

{{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [2], and [2] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: text_vectorization_4/strided_slice/

Call arguments received by layer 'text_vectorization_4' (type TextVectorization):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5,), dtype=string)


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_234264]
```

I have spent 2 weeks with this problem. Thank you for any support!

I have tried to use map() without numpy_function but I need to load feature from .npy file.
When I run in Colab GPU without num_parallel_calls, no error was thrown but It runs very slowly.

I have tried with small data. Sometimes, luckily, it runs pass an epoch. So I guess the problem is not in the data but in the way it makes parallel threads. But I don't know how to fix it.